# Updating value of a variable exported to another .js files.

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm working on a `Node.js` + `Express` web. With `Jade`, there is a `selector` in the webpage and when the `selector` changes the value, the `onchange` will call `changeValue()` in the `script.js` inside `/public/javascripts`.

I have `var selectedValue` inside `script.js` with initial value 'Mobile'. When `changeValue()` is called, I use `selectedValue = valueFromSelector;` that will change the value of `selectedValue` to whatever selected.

When I want to access `selectedValue` inside `/routes`, the value will always be 'Mobile' and it won't change when I changed the `selector` in the webpage.

```
//  File: /public/javascripts/script.js

var  selectedValue = 'Mobile';

function changeValue() {
   selectedValue = valueFromSelector;
}

exports.selectedValue = selectedValue;
```

and

```
//   File: /routes/index.js

var selectorValue = require('../public/javascripts/script');

// this will always log 'Mobile'
console.log(selectorValue.selectedValue);
```

Is there any way to update the value referenced from `script.js`?

Comment: You seem to be confusing client-side code and server-side code.  You can't do that.  Instead, use AJAX and a database.

Comment: As per the comment above - `changeValue` needs to call the server (via AJAX) and pass the new value of the `selectedValue` variable to your script on the server side.